# alter table mytable drop `folder` not work

Tags: mysql, adminer

It Seems that the word `folder` is a keyword , but how can  I delete the column once I add the `folder` ,  now I can not rename `folder` or delete it.

Comment: `folder` is not a keyword or a reserved word.  Here is a list :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this one?

`ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN folder;`